# Proper Syntax for GraphQL Query

Tags: json, api, graphql

I'm working with the OBJKT API to pull some data

Documentation - https://data.objkt.com/docs/
Explorer - https://data.objkt.com/explore/

This is my first time using GraphQL and i'm having trouble writing the syntax for the query properly:

```
var data = '{"query":"event(where: {creator_address: {_eq: "tz1SmSqHY1nfy4Wyw9igVow4okezFB4ztXG2"}})"}';
```

The error I receive is:

```
{"errors":[{"extensions":{"path":"$","code":"invalid-json"},"message":"Error in $: Failed reading: satisfy. Expecting ',' or '}' at 'tz1SmSqHY1nfy4Wyw9igVow4okezFB4ztXG2}})}'"}]}
```

I don't understand where to place the , or } .. I've tried escaping the double quotes surrounding tz1SmSqHY1nfy4Wyw9igVow4okezFB4ztXG2 but no luck

How can I send a properly formatted query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this, this should work for you
you just need to place extra pair of parenthesis inside where

```
var data = '{"query":"event({where: {creator_address: {_eq: "tz1SmSqHY1nfy4Wyw9igVow4okezFB4ztXG2"}}})"}';
```